# React / Gatsby dynamic background images in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, background-image, es6-modules, gatsby

I've got a React component that essentially does related content, showing a user the next / prev pieces of content inside of a site.

This component needs to import background images so I can use them as inline styles inside of the component. However, to know *which* background image I want to import, I have to look at the props which get defined like this:

```
<LocationRelated 
  previousLocationName="Columbus, OH"
  previousLocationPath="columbus"
  nextLocationName="St. Pete Beach, FL"
  nextLocationPath="st-pete-beach"
/>
```

But, as far as I can tell, there isn't a way to look at the props of a component before it enters React's `render` function - thus no way to do a dynamic import.

This is my broken attempt at doing this, using an ES6 template literal inside of the import:

```
import React from "react"
import pfbRelatedPrevBGImagePath from '`../../images/grid/PFB_${this.props.previousLocationPath}.jpg`'
import pfbRelatedNextBGImagePath from '`../../images/grid/PFB_${this.props.nextLocationPath}.jpg`'

class LocationRelated extends React.Component {

  render() {

    const pfbRelatedPrevBG = { 
      backgroundImage: `linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(1,1,1,0.2), rgba(2,2,2,0.2) ), url(${ pfbRelatedPrevBGImagePath })` 
    }
    const pfbRelatedNextBG = { 
      backgroundImage: `linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(1,1,1,0.2), rgba(2,2,2,0.2) ), url(${ pfbRelatedNextBGImagePath })` 
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <aside className="pfb-longform-container">
          <section className="pfb-related-content">
            <h3 className="pfb-related-content-title">Additional Locations</h3>
            <section className="pfb-related-image-container">
              <div 
                className="pfb-related-1" 
                style= { pfbRelatedPrevBG }
              >
                <p className="pfb-related-text">{ this.props.previousLocationName }</p>
              </div>
              <div 
                className="pfb-related-2"
                style= { pfbRelatedNextBG }
              >
                <p className="pfb-related-text">{ this.props.nextLocationName }</p>
              </div>
            </section>
          </section>
        </aside>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LocationRelated
```

My webpack builder errors out, saying basically it can't read `this.props.whatever` because it hasn't been defined yet when it tries to read the `import`. Is there a way to do this?

Additional note: I'm using the Gatsby static site generator for this site, but that shouldn't really impact what's happening (at least I don't think it should).

Comment: You can do something like inside render function outside return `let previousLocation; if(this.props.previousLocationName){previousLocation = this.props.previousLocationName}` else `previousLocation = <div>Loading</div>` and then instead of `{this.props.previousLocationName}` just give `{previousLocation}`

Comment: @Aaqib - I see what you are saying, but how does that help me import the right background image into the component?

Comment: You cannot use the this keyword outside the class.

Comment: @Jayavel - is there another way to do this?

Comment: if you explain me a bit more that would be helpful, I can see that pfbRelatedPrevBG  will have image url your passing and  LocationRelated  will have image url props is that correct ?

Comment: you can use `../../images/grid/PFB_${this.props.previousLocationPath}.jpg` directrly in your pfbRelatedPrevBG

Comment: @Jayavel - that's a really good idea. I tried that but the Gatsby CMS tool does some fancy image size reducing and changes the import paths for production but not the inline CSS paths in the `render()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above approach is impossible as best I can tell, but as I discovered, it's impossible for a good reason. You have to **FULLY give into the React (Gatsby) way of doing things** and my approach above was trying to do this from a Drupal/WordPress-CMS-build perspective.

Check out my revised component for `LocationRelated`:

```
import React from "react"
import Link from 'gatsby-link'

class LocationRelated extends React.Component {

  render() {

    // Setup inline style objects using ES6 template literals which pull in the correct paths from the content pages themselves
    const pfbRelatedPrevBG = { 
      backgroundImage: `linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(1,1,1,0.2), rgba(2,2,2,0.2) ), url(${ this.props.prevLocationImgPath.sizes.src })` 
    }
    const pfbRelatedNextBG = { 
      backgroundImage: `linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(1,1,1,0.2), rgba(2,2,2,0.2) ), url(${ this.props.nextLocationImgPath.sizes.src })` 
    }

    return (
      <div className="pfb-related-bg-container">
        <aside className="pfb-related-container">
          <section className="pfb-related-content">
            <section className="pfb-related-image-container">
              <Link 
                to={ this.props.prevLocationPath }
                className="pfb-related-left-arrow"
              >
                <img src= { LeftArrow } alt="Navigate to the previous location in the PFB Annual Report" />
                <div className="pfb-related-left-arrow-text">Previous</div>
              </Link>
              <Link 
                to={ this.props.prevLocationPath }
                className="pfb-related-1" 
                style={ pfbRelatedPrevBG }
              >
                <p className="pfb-related-text">{ this.props.prevLocationName }</p>
              </Link>
              <Link 
                to={ this.props.nextLocationPath }
                className="pfb-related-2"
                style= { pfbRelatedNextBG }
              >
                <p className="pfb-related-text">{ this.props.nextLocationName }</p>
              </Link>
              <Link 
                to={ this.props.nextLocationPath }
                className="pfb-related-right-arrow"
              >
                <img src= { RightArrow } alt="Navigate to the next location in the PFB Annual Report" />
                <div className="pfb-related-right-arrow-text">Next</div>
              </Link>
            </section>
          </section>
        </aside>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LocationRelated
```

You'll notice not much is different than the above attempt but pay attention to the `this.props.nextLocationImgPath.sizes.src` path being used in the `backgroundImage` object literal. You have to pass `backgroundImage` the source path as a prop. Don't try to do it in the component like I was. React's separation of concerns is about getting data out of components and instead feeding data in through props.

So then the question becomes: if you have to pass the path in as a prop, how do you get the path when you call your component at the page level?

If you're using `Gatsby` (and you should), you need to use GraphQL to get the optimized image paths. In my example, we will call for `background-image` path on the same page where we would call the `LocationRelated` component.

Simplified example of my page that concentrates on the issue at hand:

```
import React from 'react'
import Img from "gatsby-image";

import LocationRelated from '../components/LocationRelated'

class CharlotteLocation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>    
        <LocationRelated 
          prevLocationName="Detroit"
          prevLocationPath="detroit"
          prevLocationImgPath= { this.props.data.charlottePrevImage }
          nextLocationName="Montana"
          nextLocationPath="montana"
          nextLocationImgPath= { this.props.data.charlotteNextImage }
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CharlotteLocation 

// GraphQL queries for each image
export const CharlotteImageQuery = graphql`
  query CharlotteImageQuery {
    charlottePrevImage: imageSharp(id: { regex: "/PFB_DETROIT/" }) {
      sizes(maxWidth: 600 ) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes_withWebp
      }
    },
    charlotteNextImage: imageSharp(id: { regex: "/PFB_MONTANA/" }) {
      sizes(maxWidth: 600 ) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes_withWebp
      }
    }
  }
`
```

These GraphQL queries make available the optimized paths to the files we need, and now we can send them into our `LocationRelated` component via `this.props.data`.

`gatsby-image` and GraphQL are a bit tricky to work with at first so check out [this nice tutorial by Kyle Gill](https://medium.com/@kyle.robert.gill/ridiculously-easy-image-optimization-with-gatsby-js-59d48e15db6e). It got me going a bit better than the Gatsby documentation did.

For reference, here is how I set up my `gatsby-config.js` in the project to get all these plugins working nicely together (I'm pulling the images from a standalone `images` directory in my project rather than in a component, so I needed `gatsby-source-filesystem` to make all this work along with `gatsby-image`, `gatsby-transformer-sharp`, `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,):

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'PFB2017 Site',
  },
  //pathPrefix: "/pfb2017-site",
  plugins: [
    // Adds in React Helmet for metadata
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,

    // Gives us sass in the project
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,

    // This plugin transforms JSON, which is how we are storing our location data
    `gatsby-transformer-json`,

    // Adds in Gatsby image handling
    `gatsby-image`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,

    /** 
     * This is how you customize gatsby-source-filesystem
     * Check this page out for more background 
     * https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/building-with-components 
     * By default, the gatsby-default starter kit comes with the `pages` directory wired up
     * I'm adding it here for consistency but you don't need it
     * What I have added into the starter are `images` and `data`, subfolders we'll need for the PFB project
     * 
     */

    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `pages`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
      },
    },    
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `data`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/data`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`
      }
    }
  ],
};
```